# PHP : Scrape data generated with javascript ( ES6 )

Tags: php, phantomjs, scrape

I try to scrape data of some URL with phantomjs and php phantomjs , but my target page generated some of the data with ES6 and phantomjs doesn't support it yet , and I got some errors like this ( in Console log ) :

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Set
```

and my code is :

```
use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;

$client = Client::getInstance();

$client->getEngine()->setPath('C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\bin\\phantomjs.exe');

$request = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest('example.com', 'GET');

$response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();

$client->send($request, $response);
var_dump($response->getConsole());
```

I search a lot! and I found the phantomjs will support ES6 in new version ( v2.5 ) and release a beta version but it's doesn't work for me!

now, what I do? is there any way to scrape this page?

Comment: If you can ditch PHP, try puppeteer, it's like the new PhantomJS so to speak.

Comment: @Vaviloff sorry i don't know how use it ! is there any tut for learning how use this in php ?

Comment: If you dont know, you can find a tutorial, right?

Comment: @Vaviloff I searching for ' how use puppeteer with php ' but I can't find anything !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the future of PhantomJS is not yet certain, may I suggest another headless browser to use: [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer). It is based on Google Chrome headless and behind it is a separate team of Google engineers.

There are [already projects](https://packagist.org/search/?tags=puppeteer) to control it from PHP, most notable at the moment is [puphpeteer](https://github.com/extractr-io/puphpeteer)*

__
* (notable in the way that not only can it make screenshots/PDF, but it also offers javascript evaluation)